# What could be the cause for these strange UFW block entries in my syslog?

Tags: firewall, ufw, syslog

I've recently noticed a large number of recurring UFW blocks in my syslog. This surprised me as I have no UFW rules set:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip
```

Could someone more versed with firewall configurations on Ubuntu/Linux please tell me why I am getting these entries?

```
Apr  7 20:01:04 mhcUBN kernel: [18234.747861] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3586 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:03:09 mhcUBN kernel: [18359.541595] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3587 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:05:14 mhcUBN kernel: [18484.335607] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3588 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:07:19 mhcUBN kernel: [18609.129970] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3589 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:09:24 mhcUBN kernel: [18733.923467] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3590 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:10:01 mhcUBN CRON[31522]: (mhc) CMD ("/home/mhc/.scripts/Customization/Powersaving/battmonitor")
Apr  7 20:11:29 mhcUBN kernel: [18858.717504] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3591 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:13:34 mhcUBN kernel: [18983.510575] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3592 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:15:39 mhcUBN kernel: [19108.306349] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3593 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:17:01 mhcUBN CRON[582]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr  7 20:17:44 mhcUBN kernel: [19233.100675] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3594 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:19:49 mhcUBN kernel: [19357.893801] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3595 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:20:01 mhcUBN CRON[1272]: (mhc) CMD ("/home/mhc/.scripts/Customization/Powersaving/battmonitor")
Apr  7 20:21:54 mhcUBN kernel: [19482.686449] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3596 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:23:59 mhcUBN kernel: [19607.480499] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3597 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:26:04 mhcUBN kernel: [19732.274979] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3598 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:28:09 mhcUBN kernel: [19857.068910] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3599 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:30:01 mhcUBN CRON[3484]: (mhc) CMD ("/home/mhc/.scripts/Customization/Powersaving/battmonitor")
Apr  7 20:30:14 mhcUBN kernel: [19981.862231] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3600 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:32:19 mhcUBN kernel: [20106.657165] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3601 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:34:24 mhcUBN kernel: [20231.450561] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3602 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:36:29 mhcUBN kernel: [20356.244475] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3603 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:38:34 mhcUBN kernel: [20481.038479] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3604 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:40:01 mhcUBN CRON[5702]: (mhc) CMD ("/home/mhc/.scripts/Customization/Powersaving/battmonitor")
Apr  7 20:40:39 mhcUBN kernel: [20605.832618] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3605 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:42:44 mhcUBN kernel: [20730.626727] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3606 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:44:49 mhcUBN kernel: [20855.419706] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3607 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:46:54 mhcUBN kernel: [20980.214309] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3608 DF PROTO=2 
Apr  7 20:48:59 mhcUBN kernel: [21105.008870] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:04:0e:ef:71:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3609 DF PROTO=2
```

---

I have found these threads which point to a multicast problem:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1886913

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142525

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TS-775

I am no network expert by any means and don't properly understand what is actually going on. If anyone "translated" these so that I comprehend what's going on, I'd be very happy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you have some service on your local network that is advertising itself or looking for clients. It's your "default deny incoming" rule that's blocking this traffic. Yours looks much like persistent noise I see on my home network, caused by a [Multicast DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) server in my router.

mDNS multicasts to 224.0.0.251, so that's not what yours is. You have something multicasting to 224.0.0.1, a [generic "all hosts" address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address). Couldn't tell you what it is from that, but from the subnet address (x.x.x.1) I'm guessing your router is the source.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! I found a number of (German) threads describing this issue with my router model. Apparently there is no GUI setting to deactivate these packets but as it's running Linux you can manually change the configuration: http://www.searchnetworking.de/forum/messages.cfm?threadid=39135782-2F85-4EC9-9FE07BF91E077A69

Comment: I had a couple of follow-up questions concerning dealing with these events and composed a [question on unix/linux.se](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71613/how-can-i-disable-ufw-logging-for-a-specific-event). Please feel free to chime in if you feel like it.

Answer (score 11):

> My guess is that it's the local router asking if there are any hosts
> interested in receiving multicasts - nothing to worry about (see [[1]](https://ubuntuforums.org/newreply.php?p=13062562&noquote=1))

You can prevent the creation of new log entries with this command (works for me on 13.10 64 bit):

```
sudo ufw deny from 192.168.178.1 to 224.0.0.1
```

I cannot say if this will have negative side effects for *your* networked device(s).

If you want to see UFW firewall rules, type

`sudo ufw status numbered`

and if you want to get rid of it write

`sudo ufw delete 3`

if the rule you want to delete is rule number 3. Work your upwards in the rule list.